# IE11 ignoring media queries

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I can not figure out why my website does not show proper in IE11? In this browser the website shows like a mobile version on a 23" screen. It seems to me that it ignores media queries. I have tried both "@media screen" and "@media all" but no luck. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Here is the website: www.dh.hys.cz

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. There was a bracket missing after one of my media queries. This was no problem for firefox but ie did not like it. I guess I should have checked the style sheet more thoroughly before posting a question.